# Removing link '<a>' from '<li>' on meta_value in custom feilds

Tags: custom-field, links, meta-value

I want to remove all links on my custom fields.

My fields for now :

```
<li><a href="">my item</a></li>
```

and I'm trying to get this:

```
<li>my item</li>
```

This is the code I tried, but it isn't working for me.

```
function wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks( $content ) {
    preg_match_all( '!<a[^>]*? href=[\'"]#[^<]+</a>!i', $content, $matches );

    foreach ( $matches[0] as $link )
        $content = str_replace( $link, strip_tags( $link ), $content );

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'acf/load_value/name=artist', 'wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks' );
```

Comment: Why don't you go to the original code that is making the link and remove it from the list items at the source?

Comment: well suggestion from @rudtek additionally are you sure that the action hook `acf/load_value/name=artist` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try too remove all tag from content then add `li` ?

```
$content = '<li>'.strip_tags(get_field('artist')).'</li>';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i tried, isn't working for me.There is no other way ? any thinks